# What is a major tick spacing?

Tags: java, swing

I was looking at JSlider and I noticed something called

```
JSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(int n);
```

I read the description of what it does but I do not understand what a major tick is nor how it is used in a program. can you please explain to me about this concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setMajorTickSpacing%28int%29):

> The number that is passed in represents the distance, measured in
>   values, between each major tick

A major tick mark would be the larger of the tick marks. With the minor obviously being the smaller ones.

Tick marks on a slider correspond to values. Here is an example of a slider that contains 20 values:

[image]

The major ticks correspond to the values 0, 5, 10, 15, and 20.

Comment: Yes, now what is a Major Tick?

Answer (score 8):

Major ticks are the big ticks, minor ticks are the small ones:

[image]

`paintTicks` has to be enabled for them to be drawn.

The spacing is in value units. The above has range 0-100 with major tick spacing = 10 and minor tick spacing = 2:

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider();
slider.setMinimum(0);
slider.setMaximum(100);
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
slider.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
```

Spacing can be set to 0 for either tick type to disable those ticks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jslider:

[image]

The small vertical lines are the minor tick marks. The slightly bigger ones are the major tick marks. setMajorTickSpacing() sets the spacing between them.

The major ticks are also where labels (text) are shown by default if enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The number you pass into `setMajorTickSpacing` tells the JSlider how many units to separate between each larger tick. When you look at a ruler and you see the larger tick mark every inch (or centimeter, what have you), these are considered the "major tick" for JSliders.